# How to replace the `no-js` class name by `js` on all elements?

Tags: javascript, html, css

What I’m trying to do is to get the elements with the class name `no-js` and replace it with `js`.

I have no idea how to do this.
I tried Googling around but couldn’t find anything, so does anyone know how to do this?

My goal is to have a menu show a drop-down navigation when clicked, but if JavaScript is disabled I want it to show on hover with CSS (I’ve already done that).

I’ve put my code on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MrPumpkin22/v9dcC/10/).

Comment: updated my answer to show the full code to both parts of your question. 1) change class  2) make + button toggle subnav :)

Comment: All answers here are either incorrect or outdated. The correct, modern answer is `document.querySelectorAll(".no-js").forEach(({ classList }) => classList.replace("no-js", "js"));`. See [How to change all classname elements of specific classname](/a/69246456/4642212).

Answer (score 11):

You need to iterate the returned elements and replace that portion of the class name on each one:

```
var els = [].slice.apply(document.getElementsByClassName("no-js"));
for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
    els[i].className = els[i].className.replace(/ *\bno-js\b/g, "js");
}
```

Note that `getElementsByClassName` returns a "live list", which is why it's necessary to first make a copy of the return value (using `[].slice`) and  iterate that list instead).

Comment: Thank you! I was searching for the getElementById-less solution for a time. My goal was to create this Drupal hack: https://groups.drupal.org/node/10919#comment-1152470

Answer (score 7):

by javascript you can change the class name using

`document.getElementById('elementid').className = 'classname'`

if you want to add a new class by javascript use

`document.getElementById('elementid').className += ' classname'`

if you want to replace class name with other things use strings replace function

`document.getElementById('elementid').className = document.getElementById('elementid').className.replace(your replace code)`

Answer (score 5):

**look like a question, but seems to be the preferred way of doing it...**

```
(function(html){html.className = 
   html.className.replace(/\bno-js\b/,'js')})(document.documentElement);
```

**Example:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US" class="no-js">
<head itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebSite">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
    <script>(function(html){html.className = html.className.replace(/\bno-js\b/,'js')})(document.documentElement);</script>
    <title>Example Site| My Site Description</title>
```

Notice the location of this early on the document head... This ensures that it get's added immediately. This is much faster approach than a jquery alternative. I believe this is how modernizr does it.

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't the name of the `getElementsByClassName` method give you a hint that it should return not a single element but multiple elements? Because there can be many elements with the same class in the document. [Read the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByClassName) more carefully.

If you're familiar with CSS, there is [`document.querySelectorAll` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Document.querySelectorAll), which retrieves elements via CSS selectors.

```
var plusLinks = document.querySelectorAll('a.no-js')
```

Then you can access individual links by their numeric index:

```
var firstLink = plusLinks[0]
```

As for the `class` attribute (and it *is* `class` attribute, not `no-js` attribute), you shouldn't remove it, but [set it to a new value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.setAttribute).

```
firstLink.setAttribute('class', 'js')
```

Or:

```
firstLink.className = 'js'
```

Since you want to remove the hover effect, and the body element already has `no-js` class on it, you can replace the class once for the whole page:

```
document.body.className = 'js'
```

Answer (score -2):

Step 1 - get element by it's unique ID-

```
Element = Document.GetElementByID("whatever");
```

Step 2- remove the attribute class-

```
Element.RemoveAttribute("class");
```

Step 3 - create attribute class -

```
    var attribute = document.createAttribute("class");
    attribute.nodeValue = "someclassnamehere"
    Element.setAttributeNode(attribute);
```