# remove and add class with javascript on page load issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

When i add or remove a class with javascript then reload the page ..

it wont work

I tried this code, and put it in  on the header

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
  $('.boxAdRight').removeClass('boxAdRight').addClass('active');
});
</script>
```

**and this is my HTML** I want to remove the class **boxAdRight** and change it with **.active** class

```html
<div class="panel-body">
   <div class="tab-content">
      <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="data">
         <div class="getData">
            <div class="row">
               <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                  <div class="servers">
                     <ul>
                        <li class="active" 
                           id="s_0"onclick="getServer(this.id,0);"> 
                           <i class="fa fa-video-camera"></i> server1
                        </li>
                     </ul>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 fRight">
                  <div class="episodes boxAdRight">
                     <h2>episodes</h2>
                     <ul>
                        <li>
                           <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/newarticle13/">                                  episode 1</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="active"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/newarticle13/"> episode 2</a>
                        </li>
                     </ul>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-8 col-xs-12 fRight">
                  <div class="boxVideos">
                     <div class="getCode"><iframe src="https://*******" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" width="700" height="430" allowfullscreen="true" webkitallowfullscreen="true" mozallowfullscreen="true"></iframe>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

thank you

Comment: what do you mean by "it won't work?" have you checked your browser console on error messages?

Comment: thank you for your reply, yes i checked my browser, no errors !

Comment: you change the class with javascript and that's ok. Then you say you reload the page. Are you saying that you expect the change to be persistent on page reload?

Comment: @LelioFaieta That reloading page part caught my eye too, however the code should execute the same way every time the page is loaded, so I'm still confused as to what the OP's issue is. Unclear.

Comment: I'm working on wordpress, I can see the code of javascript on source code of the page, but nothing change

Comment: Wait, are you adding JavaScript to a post, or is your JavaScript in a template, plugin, or functions.php? WordPress will strip out any JavaScript you enter in a post or page.

Comment: I'm working on page, and I add the code to the <head> section on the file Header.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your .boxAdRight class with .episodes class and it'll work as you want.

```
  <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".episodes").removeClass("boxAdRight").addClass("active");
       });
    </script>
```

Comment: Works fine with it

Comment: Have you removed "episodes" class from " <div class="episodes boxAdRight">" this line?
OR 
Check in private browser or CTRL+F5. may be it's cache issue.

Answer (score 4):

As a first observation I would like to mention the fact that JQuery's removeClass function returns one or more space separated class names that should be removed. As a consequence, you should not apply addClass over the result of removeClass.

There might be other issues also in your code though...

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the order of the method calls should be

```
$('.boxAdRight').addClass('active').removeClass('boxAdRight');
```

In the original example `$('.boxAdRight').removeClass('boxAdRight').addClass('active');` the selector `.boxAdRight` is being used, but then that class is being removed with `.removeClass('boxAdRight')`, so `.addClass('active')` is being called on a selector with no matching elements.

Comment: No, this is not correct. It will work fine. Testing a simple example demonstrates this. http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/2aqt7uow/

Answer (score 0):

get it like that will solve it

```
$('.episodes').addClass('active').removeClass('boxAdRight');
```

in normal case yours too must work ?

Comment: I tried on http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/2aqt7uow/ and its working well ! if you wanna have active class. open the console with f 12 and you will see active is added to your div

Comment: yes i see, it works for you, but in my case, I'm working on wordpress, and I added the code in <head> section of header.php

Answer (score -1):

You can also simplify this code by replacing of class instead of removing it.

$('.boxAdRight').className = 'active';

[how to replace class HTML name with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8708826/how-to-replace-class-html-name-with-javascript)

Comment: thank you, I tried that code too, but tha class still